Interfacing high-speed ADC with ZYNQ 7020
I need to interface a high-speed ADC (100 Msps or higher data rate) with a ZYNQ 7020 core board, which has limited number of pins available to use (100 pins). I need to sample a 30 MHz signal with my ADC, but not continuously. I need like about 10 cycles. I have found several high-speed ADCs:

Parallel output ADCs, for example AD9650. The problem is that they occupy too many pins (more than 16 pins).
JESD204 ADCs, fore example LTC2274. They occupy a lot fewer number of pins, but problem is they need GTX pins in the ZYNQ part. My ZYNQ 7020 lacks them.
serial LVDS output ADCs, like LTC2195. The number of pins between ZYNQ board and the ADC are ok but the problem is I only have access to 96 HR banks of 34 and 35 and 8 EMIOs. The LVDS interface is only supported by HP banks as per page 91 of the Xilinx document.
Here's the screenshot:

Now, What's a possible way to connect a 100 Msps, 14 or 16 bit ADC to my 7020?


I think you've just articulated why the ZYNQ 7020 is not the FPGA for your application. Or are you stuck with that particular part?

@Neil_UK Actually I have to use ZYNQ 7020.

Do you need the full bandwidth of your 100 MS/s ADC? Could you either buffer time fragments, or decimate/filter to reduce the sample rate, with a capable FPGA, which then sends the reduced rate to the 7020?

@Neil_UK I need to sample a 30MHz signal with my ADC, but not continuously. I need like about 10 cycles. But my problem is mostly pin count (in 1) and in 2 and 3 the limited ZYNQ specifications.

If you don't need to sample continuously, can you use a capable FPGA to read the ADC and store the samples, then shift only the relevant 10 samples to the 7020 using your own design of a lower pin count, lower speed serial interface to the 7020?

@Neil_UK What specifications do I need to consider for the FPGA?


lots of inputs for a 9650 OR 2) JESD for a 2274 OR 3) fast LVDS for a 2195, AND 4) enough memory to store samples between relevant portions to be sent to the 7020 AND 5) something that you're permitted to use and able to obtain.


Can you edit the question to (a) Include a link to the "ZYNQ 7020 core board" in use (b) List which pins are available to use for the ADC interface. This is to help understanding what the options are.

@ChesterGillon I added the core board page. Based on the documents, there are 8 EMIOs and 96 PL pins from banks 34 and 35 available

I've used HR banks for LVDS on 7 series Xilinx before. Are you sure you need HP?

@user1850479 I added the screenshot in the question.

The screenshot says both HR and HP banks support LVDS.

@user1850479 no, serial lvds ADCs have 1.8V standard

LVDS voltage swing is about 400mV, not 1.8v. Your ADC uses a 1.8v supply but that's not relevant if you're using LVDS since the signal voltage is lower.
